# Trying to add a full stop at the end of the string

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning JS and I am going through the MDN web docs.  I am trying to complete this [exercise 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Test_your_skills:_Strings), which asks me to add a full stop.

When I run the code, I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

```
if (fixedQuote.str.charAt(fixedQuote.str.length-1) != ".") {
            fixedQuote.str = fixedQuote.str + "."
        }
```

This is the entire exercise.   Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
let quote = 'I dO nOT lIke gREen eGgS anD HAM';
    
    // Add your code here
    let fixedQuote = quote[0].toUpperCase() + quote.substring(1);

    fixedQuote = fixedQuote.replace("green eggs and ham", "onions");

    if (fixedQuote.str.charAt(fixedQuote.str.length-1) != ".") {
        fixedQuote.str = fixedQuote.str + "."
    }
     
    // Don't edit the code below here!
    
    section.innerHTML = ' ';
    let para1 = document.createElement('p');
    para1.textContent = fixedQuote;
    let para2 = document.createElement('p');
    para2.textContent = finalQuote;
    
    section.appendChild(para1);
    section.appendChild(para2);
```

Comment: Try `fixedQuote.charAt()`

Comment: I dont know why you used .str. Replace fixedQuote.str with fixedQuote.str

Comment: Please try out https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=46

Answer (score 1):

Just use `fixedQuote`, which is a string, not `fixedQuote.str`, which is undefined. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

```js
let quote = 'I dO nOT lIke gREen eGgS anD HAM';
    
    // Add your code here
    let fixedQuote = quote[0].toUpperCase() + quote.substring(1);

    fixedQuote = fixedQuote.replace("green eggs and ham", "onions");

    if (fixedQuote.charAt(fixedQuote.length-1) != ".") {
        fixedQuote = fixedQuote + "."
    }
     
    // Don't edit the code below here!
    section = document.querySelector("section");
    section.innerHTML = ' ';
    let para1 = document.createElement('p');
    para1.textContent = fixedQuote;
    let para2 = document.createElement('p');
    //para2.textContent = finalQuote;
    
    section.appendChild(para1);
    section.appendChild(para2);
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let fixedQuote = quote[0].toUpperCase() + quote.substring(1);
    fixedQuote = fixedQuote.replace("green eggs and ham", "onions");

    if (fixedQuote.charAt(fixedQuote.length-1) != ".") {
        fixedQuote= fixedQuote + "."
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this without the str. before charAt(), its working

```js
let quote = 'I dO nOT lIke gREen eGgS anD HAM';
    
    // Add your code here
    let fixedQuote = quote[0].toUpperCase() + quote.substring(1);

    fixedQuote = fixedQuote.replace("green eggs and ham", "onions");

    if (fixedQuote.charAt(fixedQuote.length - 1) != ".") {
        fixedQuote = fixedQuote + "."
    }

    console.log(fixedQuote);
```